# 'SubmitHandler' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs

Line 1:10:   'getDefaultNormalizer' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 5:9:    'adminUser' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
Line 9:15:   'setUser' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
Line 10:10:  'error' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
Line 10:16:  'setError' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
Line 12:9:   'Login' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
Line 15:9:   'Logout' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
Line 23:20:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='               eqeqeq

src\components\LoginForm.js
Line 5:11:  'SubmitHandler' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: It looks like warning

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there would be ESLint config `.eslintrc.json` file that makes an `ESLint` error out if there are unused variables. Every `ESLint` rule has a name: this rule is called `no-unused-vars`. So these are warnings rather than errors.
Please [Read the Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)